# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm having a strange issue trying to add a rewrite rule.

Firstly, a note about my set-up. I'm using a date.php file for another specific set-up on the site.

The area I'm having issues with is a customized Archives page.
In order to not mess with the date.php template I attempted to set up a new page within wordpress and then created my own template to display the archives.

In order to catch the url with the date and not redirect to the date.php I set up the following add_rewrite_rules :

```
function my_archives() {

    add_rewrite_rule("my-archives/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$", 'index.php?pagename=my-archives&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]', 'top');

    add_rewrite_rule("my-archives/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$", 'index.php?pagename=my-archives&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]', 'top');    

}

add_action('init', 'my_archives');
```

I thought everything was a-ok as my links were working correctly.
Example: 
http://mysite.com/my-archives/2013/09/ 
as well as 
http://mysite.com/my-archives/2013/09/page/2/
for paged results.

Now a month later I see that for some reason it'll only correctly redirect to dates that are one month behind the current date.
So being that the current date is 2013/10/ it's only redirecting /2013/09/ and everything else is being redirected to the 404 page.

Any suggestions on probable cause for this or if someone sees something in my code that is incorrect it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you by any chance simply not having any results for that query?

Are you hooking to the WordPress query in order to make sure that WordPress understands the query correctly(it's possible that WordPress is trying to find a page with slug "my-archives" within the specified year and month - and when it can't it shows a 404 error).

Try doing the following:

```
var_dump( get_posts( 'pagename=my-archives&year=2013&monthnum=10' ) );
```

and see if that returns any results. If it doesn't - then that's most-likely your issue.

To work-around that, I would advise that you change your rewrite rules to something like:

```
add_rewrite_rule("my-archives/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$", 'index.php?pagename=my-archives&my_year=$matches[1]&my_monthnum=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

Since I assume that if you're not hooking to the main WordPress query, you are executing the query on your custom page template. There you should look for the `my_year` and `my_monthnum` query variables instead of `year` and `month`.

Keep in mind, that actually modifying the main WordPress query(on the either `parse_request`(passes the `$wp` object and not `$wp_query`) or the `pre_get_posts` action(passes the `$wp_query` object) ) might be a better solution.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the sound advice. Just had to add in a couple of my own vars using the add_query_vars_filter and change out the month_num and year variables for my own. All working great now.